# How to remove the banner article name in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5

This is my link that shows a picture of the page we are working on:

[image: Image of website we're working on]

How is it possible to remove the articles header of each content page in Joomla 2.5?

Answer (score 1):

try the following steps:

1. login to the admin panel
2. click on menu manager
3. edit your menu
4. edit your menu item
5. update the option Parameters (System) > Show Page Title to **No**

[please checkout this screenshot](http://snag.gy/c9eGi.jpg)